# I am trying to filter rows, but they are still showing up in my boxplot

Tags: python, filtering

How would I go about removing unwanted categories from my boxplot? I have done this before and only categories I wanted are in the output, but this time I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

```
 east_africa_filter = ['Ethiopia', 'Kenya', 'Rwanda', 'Tanzania', 'Uganda']
 EA_filter = df[df.Origin.isin(east_africa_filter)]
 
 EA_filter.Origin.unique()
 
 len(EA_filter)
 
 sns.set(style='darkgrid', palette='muted', color_codes = True)
 
 ax = sns.boxplot(data=EA_filter, x='Origin', y='TotalCupPoints', orient = 'v', color='lightgray')
 plt.setp(ax.artists, alpha=0.5)
 
 sns.stripplot(x='Origin', y= 'TotalCupPoints', data=EA_filter, jitter=True, size=6, linewidth=0, hue='Process')
```

Here is a picture of the boxplot. What is the best way to filter out those unwanted categories?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You show the commands but not their outputs. What is the output of `EA_filter.Origin.unique()`?

Comment: @DYZ [Ethiopia, Uganda, Kenya, Rwanda]
Categories (4, object): [Ethiopia, Uganda, Kenya, Rwanda]

Comment: @DYZ I finally figured it out. It was a problem not shown. I had them as categories, but they needed to be changed to objects. Thank you for the help!